# NLog prevents update database in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, logging, asp.net-core-webapi, nlog

I'm using NLog in my ASP.NET Core Web API project.
I have and issue in **Update-Database** while using **NLog** 
This is my NLog.Config file in my application :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="true"
      internalLogLevel="Trace"
      internalLogFile="C:\Nlog\logs\internalLog.txt">

    <targets>
        <target xsi:type="Database"
            name="dbTarget"
            connectionString="${configsetting:item=ConnectionStrings.DefaultConnection}"
            commandText="INSERT INTO [app].[TblApplicationLog](Logged,Message,Level,Exception,Logger,Url,UserName,ServerName,Ip,Controller,Action,Host,Application,Callsite,UserAuthenticated, Useragent)
                VALUES (@datetime,@msg,@level,@exception,@logger,@url,@username,@servername,@ip,@controller,@action,@host,@application,@callsite,@userAuthenticated,@useragent)">
            <parameter name="@application" layout="AspNetCoreNlog" />
            <parameter name="@datetime" layout="${date}" />
            <parameter name="@msg" layout="${message}" />
            <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
            <parameter name="@exception" layout="${exception:innerFormat=Message,StackTrace}" />
            <!--<parameter name="@trace" layout="${stacktrace}" />-->
            <parameter name="@callsite" layout="${callsite}" />
            <parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}" />
            <parameter name="@url" layout="${aspnet-request-url}" />
            <parameter name="@username" layout="${aspnet-user-identity}" />
            <parameter name="@servername" layout="${machinename}" />
            <parameter name="@ip" layout="${aspnet-request-ip}" />
            <parameter name="@controller" layout="${aspnet-mvc-controller}" />
            <parameter name="@action" layout="${aspnet-mvc-action}" />
            <parameter name="@host" layout="${aspnet-request-host}" />
            <parameter name="@useragent" layout="${aspnet-request-useragent}" />
            <parameter name="@userAuthenticated" layout="${aspnet-user-isauthenticated}" />
        </target>
    </targets>

    <rules>
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="dbTarget" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Everything in logging works fine but if I add a new migration and wanna do **update-database**, I get following error in NuGet Package Manager Console:

> An error occurred while writing to logger(s). (Timeout expired.  The
> timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the
> server is not responding.)

**Note: When I exclude the Nlog.config file from my solution, Update-Database works fine like always, but with including Nlog.config file in my solution, Update-database won't work anymore**

Comment: I think there's some kind of Lock in the DB that prevents the logger from writing logs into the db during migration.

Comment: @keuleJ How can I find it if there is one ?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was from this line of code in my NLog.Conif file
in line number 5 = `throwException="true"`
After I removed this line, update database done